# Creating a new unique dataset from dates and categories in R

Tags: r, date, dataframe, unique, categorical-data

I have a dataframe that has OrderDate and MajorCategory as the two variables. OrderDates range from 2005-01-01 to 2007-12-31, and MajorCategory runs from 1 to 73 with around 35.5 million entries. Each OrderDate references a specific order, which has an ID number and also is attributed to a specific MajorCategory. I am trying to create a dataframe to show each unique OrderDate and the count of each MajorCategory that was ordered on that date.

The dataset currently looks something like:

```
OrderDate   MajorCategory
2005-12-12  66
2005-12-12  66
2006-03-28  43
2006-05-16  66
```

I have separated the unique OrderDate (after changing the class to Date) into its own dataframe by using:

```
OD <- as.data.frame(unique(DMEFLines3Dataset2$OrderDate))
OD <- as.data.frame(sort(OD$`unique(DMEFLines3Dataset2$OrderDate)`))
```

I'm not sure how to get the MajorCategory to show me a count for each date. So the desired output would be something like:

```
OD          MC_1    MC_2
2005-01-01  4       6
2005-01-02  7       45
2005-01-03  3       23
```

where OD is the Order Date and MC_X is the MajorCategory's order count per date (MC_1 to MC_73).

I tried using for loops, frequency, and count, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Ray, could you show us an example of your dataset? You can use `dput()` to output it for us. Please edit your question and add this information, then we can help you much more easily.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an R expert, and if given the option I would try to aggregate the data as needed in a different language and then load the aggregated data into an R data frame for any further analysis.

I have done something close to what you are asking by calculating ROC graphs from the output of a third party naive bayes model which consisted of appointment detail grouped by departments. Tweaking my code a bit,  I was able to get a dataframe with counts of an identifier grouped by date, which seems to be structured the way you are asking for.

```
    library(RODBC)

dbConnection <- 'Driver={SQL Server};Server=SERVERNAME;Database=DBName;Trusted_Connection=yes'
channel <- odbcDriverConnect(dbConnection)

InputDataSet <- sqlQuery(channel, "
SELECT OrderID, OrderDate, MajorCategory from [dbo].[myDataSet];"
)

results <- data.frame("date", "ordCount")
names(results) <- c("date", "ordCount")
for (dt in unique(InputDataSet$OrderDate)) {
    ordCount <- 0
    filteredSet = InputDataSet[InputDataSet$OrderDate == dt,]
    for (mc in unique(filteredSet$MajorCategory)) {
        ordCount <- ordCount+1
    }

    df <- data.frame(dt, ordCount)
    names(df) <- c("date", "ordCount")
    results <- rbind(df, results)
}


results
```

Answer (score 0):

```
OrderDate<- as.Date(c('2005-12-12','2005-12-12','2006-03-28','2006-05-16','2005-03-04','2005-12-12'))
MajorCategory<- as.numeric(c(66, 66, 43, 66, 43, 1))
OD=data.frame(OrderDate,MajorCategory)

out <- split(OD, OD$MajorCategory)
count=lapply(out, function(x) aggregate(x$MajorCategory, FUN = length, by = list(x$OrderDate)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- df %>%
  group_by(OrderDate, MajorCategory) %>%
  tally() %>%
  mutate(MajorCategory = paste("MC", MajorCategory, sep="_")) %>%
  spread(MajorCategory, n)
df1
```

**Output is:**

```
  OrderDate  MC_43 MC_66 MC_67
1 2005-12-12    NA     2     1
2 2006-03-28     1    NA    NA
3 2006-05-16    NA     1    NA
```

**Sample data:**

```
df <- structure(list(OrderDate = c("2005-12-12", "2005-12-12", "2005-12-12", 
"2006-03-28", "2006-05-16"), MajorCategory = c(66L, 66L, 67L, 
43L, 66L)), .Names = c("OrderDate", "MajorCategory"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```